# Android - Rotating Screen programmatically does not allow me to set visibility of a layout after?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an Android App and I have an activity where once the user presses a button, the rotation changes from portrait to landscape, and I am setting the visibility of a RelativeLayout to visible.

Here is my code:

```
public void graphEnlarge(View view){

    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

If I remove the `setRequestedOrientation`, my relativeLayout shows without problems. Since I want to show the layout in landscape, I have to put that code. However, when I put that request to landscape, I can't seem to show my layout with setVisibility.

I also tried to put the setVisibility after I set the orientation but it does not seem to work and my relativeLayout isn't showing.

Comment: I think the problem is when you change the orientation of the activity it is recreated  and layout goes to initial visible state.

Comment: adding this to your activity in the manifest android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" will solve the problem.

Comment: Yo man make your 2nd comment an answer. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when you change the orientation of the activity it is recreated and layout goes to initial visible state. So adding this to your activity in the manifest `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` will solve the problem.

Comment: Actually if you read my question, I stated there that I tried changing the visible state /after/ I switched orientation. :-)